# Join request on a collection

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I want to make a join request on a collection object in Magento. I use this :

```
$sets = Mage::getModel('magasin/geodecoupage')->getCollection()
        ->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(array("i18n" => 'geo_decoupage_i18n'), 'i18n.geo_decoupage_id = main_table.id');
```

I get the good sql request when I echo $sets, but how can I execute it and work with the result?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the Zend select object to `$sets`. Here is how to assign the collection instead and then perform a join afterwards.

```
$sets = Mage::getModel('magasin/geodecoupage')->getCollection();
$sets->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(array("i18n" => 'geo_decoupage_i18n'), 'i18n.geo_decoupage_id = main_table.id');

// and now for an example
foreach ($sets as $item) {
    var_dump($item->debug()); // prints out the loaded attributes and values
}
```